# bought computer with ubuntu program messed up

Tags: drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bought computer with messed up Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194350/bought-computer-with-messed-up-ubuntu)

i recently got a dell inspiron B130 with an ubuntu prgm on it and the main users desktop is scattered allover the place , files everywhere but not in folders,how do i fix this? i am new working with this operating system ,used to windows versions. if i go into a guest profile the desktop is perfectly fine and everything works but i cannot make the system fix itself or  don't really know where to start help???????
i have the user name and password and can get to terminal screen , but not sure how to remove and add myself to admin use

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ubuntu

Personally I would want to start afresh and completely reinstall Ubuntu. This way you can shape it to how you would like it and not put up with someone else's stuff on it.

full installation instructions can be found here  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

You can download the image from here
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Have fun with Ubuntu and if you are not sure of anything don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Linda if possible connect your computer to your router with a cable before you start the fresh install http://www.linlap.com/wiki/Dell+Inspiron+B130